# HTML5 date picker not showing inside bootstrap modal

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Can someone assist me on this one. I'm using the default HTML5 date picker however calendar is not showing inside a modal.

```
<div id="detailsModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="detailsTitle">Applicant Details</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="detailsBody">
              <div class="card card-user">
                <div class="card-body details-group">
                  <div class="form-group">
                <label for="birthdate">Birth Date</label>
                <input type="date" name="birthdate" id="birthdate" class="form-control" placeholder="Birth Date">
              </div>        
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I'm using this [native bootstrap](https://thednp.github.io/bootstrap.native/) library as I'm not using any jquery.

Comment: Can you create a working snippet with your issue?

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 date picker may have limited support across different browsers. The calendar/date picker seems to appear on the latest version of Chrome for me, however it does not work for me when I test on Safari. What did you test it with?

See the links below for the browser support:

• https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

• https://caniuse.com/input-datetime